# How do I access my Firefox addon toolbar button from the js code?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, add-on

I am new to Firefox addon development and just figured out how to add a XUL toolbarbutton to the browser's toolbar.

I'm not sure, however, how to get a handle to that button from my js code.

I need to swap the image on the button when certain content is found within a web page.

Just to be clear, my issue is not locating the page content, but making my toolbarbutton "react" to it.

Thanks!

Comment: You use `document.getElementById()`. Otherwise - please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue, I managed to get a mouseover event attached to a button.  [See my thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34344292/1038866).

It's a bit complicated.  You have to add `addEventListener` to the xul `node`.