# How to add stylesheet to toolbar

Tags: css, firefox-addon-sdk

Using the Firefox Addon SDK, I am creating a toolbar with several buttons and I want to create a mouseover effect for the buttons.

At first I thought to use a [mouseover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322949/firefox-addon-sdk-onmouseover-event-for-a-button/34344292#34344292), but then I would have to create a `mouseout` event to return it to normal, so I figured the best way would be to use css

In my old XUL version of my addon I was able to attach the stylesheet by linking to it in the XUL code and just add css for my `#buttonID`, which worked perfectly.

But how do I add the css stylesheet for my toolbar using the Addon SDK?

Here's what I've tried so far (which does not produce any errors), but I think this is just for content; if this *is* correct, then I'm not sure how to bind to the element:

```
const { browserWindows } = require("sdk/windows");
const { loadSheet } = require("sdk/stylesheet/utils");


//This is how to load an external stylesheet
for(let w of browserWindows){
    loadSheet(viewFor(w), "./myStyleSheet.css","author"  );
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
var Style = require("sdk/stylesheet/style").Style;
let myStyle = Style({source:'./myStyleSheet.css'});
for(let w of browserWindows){ 
    attachTo(myStyle, viewFor(w))
};
```

And this:

```
var { attach, detach } = require('sdk/content/mod');
const { browserWindows } = require("sdk/windows");
var { Style } = require('sdk/stylesheet/style');

var stylesheet = Style({
  uri: self.data.url('myStyleSheet.css')
});

for(let w of browserWindows){ 
    attach(stylesheet, viewFor(w))
};
```

And here is my css:

```
#myButton:hover{list-style-image(url("./icon-16b.png")!important; }
```

Comment: When you say toolbar, are you talking like a toolbar on a webpage that your addon loads or a toolbar in the browser window?

Comment: It's a Firefox Toolbar built with the Firefox Addon SDK.  It's an addon toolbar for the browser.

Comment: have you looked at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/stylesheet_style

Comment: yes, thanks for looking though; I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this in Browser Toolbox:

```
const { require } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/require.js"); // skip this in SDK
const { browserWindows: windows } = require("sdk/windows");
const { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
const { attachTo } = require("sdk/content/mod");
const { Style } = require("sdk/stylesheet/style");
let style = Style({ source: "#my-button{ display: none!important; }" });
// let self = require("sdk/self");
// let style = Style({ uri: self.data.url("style.css") });

for (let w of windows)
    attachTo(style, viewFor(w));
```

The commented part allows to load from a stylesheet file in the addon `data` directory.

Notice that you need to import SDK loader to use it in the toolbox.
When in an SDK addon, just use `require` directly.

**NB**: there is a difference in spelling: `self.data.url` vs `{ uri }`

See [self/data documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data).

**NB2**: SDK uses a custom widget ID scheme for [toggle](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/addon-sdk/source/lib/sdk/ui/button/toggle.js#35) and [action](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/addon-sdk/source/lib/sdk/ui/button/action.js#35) buttons so your button ID might not be what you expect:

```
const toWidgetId = id => 
    ('toggle-button--' + addonID.toLowerCase()+ '-' + id).replace(/[^a-z0-9_-]/g, '');
```

OR

```
const toWidgetId = id =>
    ('action-button--' + addonID.toLowerCase()+ '-' + id).replace(/[^a-z0-9_-]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

using this code, you should be able to use the mouse over or hover to change how it looks.

```
#buttonID {
  //Normal state css here
}
#buttonID:hover {
  //insert css stuff here
}
```

Comment: No.  It's not so simple or I wouldn't have posted.  This is using Firefox Addon SDK.  The question is how to add the stylesheet to the sdk toolbar - not how to add `:hover` to an id element.

Comment: Oh, I gotcha. Didn't think it would be that simple. I'll see what I can find

Answer (score 0):

This goes in the javascript file:

```
const { browserWindows } = require("sdk/windows");
const { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
const { loadSheet } = require("sdk/stylesheet/utils");
const { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");
var StyleUtils = require('sdk/stylesheet/utils');

var myButton = ActionButton({
    id: "mybutton",
    label: "My Button",
    icon: { "16": "./icon-16.png", "32":"./icon-32.png", "64": "./icon-64.png" },
    onClick: function(state) {
        console.log("mybutton '" + state.label + "' was clicked");
    }  
});

//this is how you attach the stylesheet to the browser window
function styleWindow(aWindow) {
    let domWin = viewFor(aWindow);
    StyleUtils.loadSheet(domWin, "chrome://myaddonname/content/myCSSfile.css", "agent");  
}
windows.on("open", function(aWindow) {
  styleWindow(aWindow);
});
styleWindow(windows.activeWindow);
```

And here is the css for that

```
//don't forget to add the .toolbarbutton-icon class at the end
#action-button--mystrippedadonid-mybuttonid .toolbarbutton-icon,{ 
    background-color: green;
}
```

There are several gotchas here.

- First, as of this posting, you should not use capital letters in the `id` for the button because they get *completely removed* - only lowercase letters and hyphens are allowed.
- The id of the element is not the same as the id you gave it in the button declaration. See below for how to come up with this identifier.
- To specify `content` in the url for the stylesheet file (in the loadSheet function call) you will *also* need to create a `chrome.manifest` in the root of your addon folder, and put this in it: `content   spadmintoolbar  data/` where "data" is the name of a real directory in the root folder.  I needed a `data/` folder so I could load icons for the button declarations, but you need to declare your virtual directories in `chrome.manifest` which `jpm init` does not do for you.

**How to get the element id for your css file:**

The easy way to get the `id` for your button element for use in an external style sheet is by testing your addon and then using the browser-toolbox's inspector to locate the element, whence you can fetch the id from the outputted code.

However, if you want to figure it yourself, try this formula.

- `[button-class]` = the sdk class for the button.  An Action Button becomes `action-button`
- `[mybuttonid]` = the `id` you gave the button in the sdk button declaration
- `[myaddonname]` = the `name` you gave the addon in it's `package.json` file.
- `[strippedaddonid]` = take the `id` you assigned the addon in the `package.json` file, and remove any @ symbol or dots and change it to all lowercase.

Now put it all together (don't include the square brackets):

```
`#[button-class]--[strippedaddonid]-[mybuttonid]]`
```

An example:  `action-button--myaddonsomewherecom-mybutton`

**Really simple isn't it?!**

*credit for the stylesheet attach code goes to `mconley`*