# How to use CSS :hover on a toolbar button in Addon SDK

Tags: css, firefox-addon-sdk

My addon was originally built in XUL and I am trying to redesign it using the addons SDK, and am having troubles getting icons to change/highlight when I hover the mouse over them.

[I know how to apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344417/how-to-add-stylesheet-to-toolbar/34363722#34363722) a css stylesheet to an Addon SDK toolbar and its elements (and how to fetch the right `#id` to use).  This allows me to change the `background-color` on a button, but I can't seem to make `:hover` work to change the button image.

It works if I [assign a javascript listener for a mouseover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322949/firefox-addon-sdk-onmouseover-event-for-a-button/34344292#34344292) to the button, but if I have lots of buttons or menu items then this is way overkill compared to css.

One problem is that the button image is set on the sdk button element and it is an attribute of the button.

Now, I have tried using a transparent image for the button element's attribute and then using css to supply the image.  Using XUL I would apply the image for the button or menu item with `list-style-image`.

So, my question is: How do I get `:hover` working in my css for an SDK toolbar button?

Comment: anything lacking in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [toolbarbutton-icon XUL binding](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/widgets/toolbarbutton.xml#80):

```
<binding id="toolbarbutton-image"
  extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/toolbarbutton.xml#toolbarbutton">
  <content>
    <xul:image class="toolbarbutton-icon" xbl:inherits="src=image"/>
  </content>
</binding>
```

`xbl:inherits="src=image"` means that the image inherits its `src` attribute from the `image` attribute of the `<toolbarbutton>` thus `list-style-image` CSS is ignored.

The image property is set when you create the button with SDK APIs. While it is true that you cannot create an SDK button without an image, you can cheat the system either by removing the `image` attribute afterwards or by using a transparent image and then styling it with `background-image` just like in the normal web:

```
const { browserWindows: windows } = require("sdk/windows");
const { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
const { attachTo } = require("sdk/content/mod");
const { Style } = require("sdk/stylesheet/style");
const { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

var myButton = ActionButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: "My Button",
    icon: { "24": "./transparent24.png" },
});

let self = require("sdk/self");
let path = self.data.url(); // alternatively use chrome.manifest to register resource or chrome path
let widgetId = "action-button--toolkitrequire-my-button"; // get this from the Browser Toolbox

let css = `
    #${widgetId} .toolbarbutton-icon {
        background-image: url(${path}/icon24.png);
        max-width: 24px;
    }
    #${widgetId}:hover .toolbarbutton-icon {
        background-image: url(${path}/icon24-hover.png);
    }`;

let style = Style({ source: css }); // or { uri: `${path}/style.css` }
for (let w of windows)
    attachTo(style, viewFor(w));
```

Keep in mind that other styling may apply to the image so you better use [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) to inspect the DOM. I am overriding `max-width` in this example.

Comment: I can't get this to work using an **external style sheet**.  The `:hover` part just never works for the image.  It works fine for changing the background colour, but not the image.

Comment: @bgmCoder does the code here work then, sans the external part? Are you using a transparent image?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried it with the inline css, but using the css file, I have basically replicated everything you have.  I am using the transparent image, yes.  And my css url is correct.  It's been awhile; let me try it again.

Comment: Okay, I tried this above in a completely fresh addon.  I matched the widgetID from the toolbox, I matched the icon names and put them in the `data` folder, but the icon never appears on the toolbar, although the button is there.  And if I set the `background-color` the color shows.  The images never show at all.

Comment: Oh - and that's running the addon with a fresh profile.